# The suggested edits page should show tags

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, suggested-edits

The [suggested edits page](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits) doesn't show tags for the question associated with the edit unless the tags were edited.  But the tags have important information that may be required to understand the suggestion.  For instance, there are a lot of languages with C-like syntax, and without the tags it's not always obvious which language is being used.

I think the question's tags should be shown near the top of the suggested edit, as this would help people determine whether it's a topic they know something about.

Answer (score 4):

Done,

Good suggestion, hope it helps.

Comment: I don't see it on SO. Not deployed yet?

Comment: Will be next time we deploy